Cookie-session only works within the route I apply the data to
I am working on a project in express. I need to get certain fields from a login route into a session on the backend, so I can call the data from different routes. The problem is that when I try to access the data in a different route from where I save it, it doesn't work. I am using cookie-session.
Below I include the relevant code and error
Error:
Error fetching tickets: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
    at C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\routes\ticketsystem.js:14:67
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\ARP-Website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)


App.js:
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('cookie-session');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Import MongoDB client
const client = require('./dbClient');

app.use(session({
  name: 'session',
  keys: [process.env.SESSION_SECRET],
}));

Auth.js
// Login route
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { usernameoremail, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const usersCollection = client.db('DB').collection('users');
    const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
      $or: [{ username: usernameoremail }, { email: usernameoremail }]
    });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { userId: user._id, username: user.username, email: user.email, role: user.role },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '1h' }
    );

    // Store in cookie-session
    req.session.user = {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      role: user.role,
    };

It is the same for the register route.
ticketsystem.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Import MongoDB client
const client = require('../dbClient');

const ticketsCollection = client.db('DB').collection('tickets');

// get user tickets
router.get('/tickets', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = req.session.user;
        
        const tickets = await ticketsCollection.find({ user: user.username }).toArray();

        res.json(tickets);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tickets:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;

What I've tried

I tried multiple libraries such as express-session and cookie parser.
I tried multiple configurations for the middleware.
I made sure that it was above all routes in app.js.

If anyone would be so kind to help me with this, I would really appreciate it!

You mention app.py - does that mean you access your server using a python program and not from a browser?

Hi, Please see if this post is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78862356/express-session-variable-is-undefined-on-other-routes-after-defining-it-in-the-l/78864341#comment139053294_78864341
